# GCP VPC Service Controls Allow for Downloads out of VM SSH Browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have been attempting to use VPC Service Controls with GCP VMs and have noticed that if you SSH through the console browser session you are able to download files out of the VM through the setting/cog wheel in the top right of the session. I thought the main point of having VPC service controls was to limit the ability to exfiltrate data out of your perimeter.

Maybe I have configured things on my end incorrectly. Are you inherently able to download out of the VM if you have an access level configured to enter the restricted services within a perimeter?

Has anyone else come across this or have a way to solve for this?

Answer (score 0):

When using access levels with VPC Service Controls, certain [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/use-access-levels) apply:

1- Access levels only allow requests from outside a perimeter for the resources of a protected service inside a perimeter.

You cannot use access levels to allow requests from a protected service inside a perimeter for resources outside the perimeter. If you need a protected service to make requests for resources outside the perimeter, try using [perimeter bridges](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/share-across-perimeters).

2- Requests for a protected resource in a perimeter that originate from another perimeter will always be denied, even if an access level would normally allow the external request. For more information, read about [requests between perimeters.](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/troubleshooting#requests-between-perimeters)

For [troubleshooting](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/troubleshooting) VPC access control.